# Can I customise (limit, reorder) Swype language choices?

Tags: swype

I regularly use three languages in swype. I can switch between them by long-pressing on Q, but they happen to be inconveniently spread across the list (one near the top, one in the middle, and one near the bottom).

Anyone know if I can (a) limit the list (e.g. by uninstalling specific swype language packs) or (b) reorder it? Or have another solution I haven't thought of?

Comment: In case it matters: the phone is a Samsung Galaxy S, Swype version is 2.6.47.11856.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Swype only comes in two sets: full (all languages) and a English/Spanish set.

However, there is a hidden feature: [you can swype from the Swype key to the Q key to switch between your current language and the last language you used.](http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?1351-Preferred-languages&highlight=choose%20languages)

Comment: Nice, thanks! ... If only it cycled through three...

Comment: @Tikitu I'm glad you asked because I had no idea about this shortcut until I looked it up for you :)  I was previously holding Q to switch between English <-> Spanish

Answer (score 1):

If the Swype developers don't put the options you want in the app then the only way to accomplish what you want is to get your hands on the source code and make the changes manually.

This would be quite a trick, as Swype is closed source.  I also wouldn't recommend modifying the .apk that they've released (is there even a way to decompile .apk's?) as your results could vary widely between "Swype stopped working" and "I've somehow bricked my phone".

Bryan's suggestion will definitely help you if you happen to switch between two of those three languages most of the time, but unfortunately if you cycle through all three pretty regularly you're going to have to stick with using the menu selections.

Comment: There are a few ways to decompile APKs, though none of them are entirely reliable.  Also from what I understand, Swype takes their beta feedback fairly seriously; Tikitu could always request this as a feature.

Comment: Definitely not up for hacking swype... Thanks Matthew for the suggestion, I will do that.